# Android Intent createChooser()

Tags: android, android-intent

My goal is to create an Implicit Intent and use the
Intent.createChooser() method to select an application for viewing a web page
I was told i needed to create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity will carry out.

My first question is why do i need 2 intents for this? Why can't I just use baseIntent and put it inside the  createChooser() method?

My second question is why does my application not show the menu where I can choose which application to open my URL?

Can someone also check my intent filters to see if I got them all.

MainActivity.java

```
static private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";

// For use with app chooser
static private final String CHOOSER_TEXT = "Load " + URL + " with:";



private void startImplicitActivation() {


Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

Uri webpage = Uri.parse(URL);
Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,webpage);

Intent chooserIntent = null;


startActivity(Intent.createChooser(baseIntent,CHOOSER_TEXT));
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <data android:mimeType="string"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was told i needed to create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity will carry out.

Not necessarily.

> My first question is why do i need 2 intents for this?

You don't.

> Why can't I just use baseIntent and put it inside the createChooser() method?

You certainly can do that. What `createChooser()` does, mostly, is *force* a chooser.

Suppose the user has both Chrome and Firefox installed on their Android device, and you use `ACTION_VIEW` to try to bring up a Web page in a browser.

If you use the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` directly, and if the user has chosen one of those browsers as the default browser (from some previous `ACTION_VIEW` request), the `Intent` will be routed to the default browser. If the user has not chosen a default browser, the user is presented with a chooser, so the user can choose which of the two Web browsers to use. That chooser will have a way for the user to make their choice the default browser for future requests.

If, on the other hand, you use `createChooser()` to wrap your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, your `startActivity()` call will always bring up a chooser, even if the user has chosen a default Web browser. And, this chooser will not have an option for the user to set a default.

Hence, usually, you do not use `createChooser()`, unless you feel that there is significant risk that the user's default will not be the right choice for this circumstance. You will typically see `createChooser()` used with `ACTION_SEND`, as that is a *very* generic request, one where defaults may not be the appropriate course of action.

> My second question is why does my application not show the menu where I can choose which application to open my URL?

If, when you use `createChooser()`, the user is taken directly to an activity, that is because that activity is the one-and-only match for the `Intent`. So, for example, if the user only has one Web browser installed, and you use `ACTION_VIEW` to bring up a URL, the system is not going to present a chooser for just one Web browser, but instead will just route the request to that one browser.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! What about the intent filters? Do you know if they are correct ? Have I defined the right <action>,<category> and <data> elements?

Comment: @JasonWan: "Do you know if they are correct ?" -- well, `string` is not a MIME type. Home screens -- the typical app that looks for `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activities -- will not put a MIME type on their `Intent` structures. Hence, this activity will not be started by a home screen launcher. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish here. If you are trying to have an activity respond to `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER`, and also respond to `VIEW`/`BROWSABLE`/MIME type, use two separate `<intent-filter>` elements, one for each structure.

Comment: In AndroidManifest.xml file, add the appropriate Intent Filter to
MyBrowserActivity so that Android will know that this Activity can view web pages. To
indicate that the Activity can handle this type of Intent, you will need to add an <intent-filter>
to the <activity> in Lab3b_MyBrowser’s AndroidManifest.xml file. Be sure to add the correct
<action>, <category>, and <data> elements to an <intent-filter> element.

Comment: @JasonWan: Correct. The key words there are "add an `<intent-filter>`". You added elements to an *existing* `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: @JasonWan: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean by that.

Comment: How would we know if the intent filters that we placed are working correctly or working as intended?

Comment: @JasonWan: Call `startActivity()` with an `Intent` that you think matches the `<intent-filter>`, and see what happens.