# ACTION_VIEW directly opens the URL chrome browser instead of showing options for different browsers

Tags: android, android-intent, android-chrome

Here is part of my code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, URI.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Open the link in: ");

startActivity(chooser);
```

Some extra information:

1. I have multiple browsers installed like Chrome, Firefox and others.
2. I tried clearing the Chrome defaults, cache and other application data by going to Settings > App Manager.

Other similar questions like:

[Show browser list when opening a link in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400621/show-browser-list-when-opening-a-link-in-android/17400779) shows the code that I am using as solution.

[Action_view intent not showing browser options in chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705591/action-view-intent-not-showing-browser-options-in-chooser) or don't have an accepted answer.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/28492633/12709358

Comment: Thanks @AjithkumarMuthukumaran but that solution doesn't help me. I have tried the same code and it doesn't show me the option to choose a browser.

Comment: I have tried with your code its working perfectly! Did you tried with ```<intent-filter>``` ?

Comment: @AjithkumarMuthukumaran How do I add intent filter? I have never done Android programing before. Also, did it work for you without the intent filter?

Comment: Yes working on my emulator. check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/33599836/12709358

Comment: Thanks @AjithkumarMuthukumaran This helped me understand a few things. My smartphone has multiple browsers but it has set Chrome to default. I can change the default browser to something else. However, there is no option to remove all default browsers.

Comment: The other answer said that `createChooser()` will always show a list of browsers even if default browser is set. Is this behavior vendor specific?

Comment: May I know your device brand and android version?